# Unexpected error when compiling reactjs-datepicker

Tags: css, reactjs, datepicker

I'm using gulp for my project. I'm using reactjs-datepicker but the CSS files for the module is causing some trouble.

I'm getting this error when running gulp.

```
C:\Work\Repos\Project\public\components\node_modules\react-datepicker\dist\react-datepicker.css:1
.react-datepicker__tether-element-attached-top .react-datepicker__triangle, .react-datepicker__tether-element-attached-bottom .react-datepicker__triangle, .react-datepicker__year-read-view--down-arrow, .react-datepicker__month-read-view--down-arrow {
^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: If I recall correctly, I ran into the same issue about a year ago in a project I was working on. Not sure why the error is. I used [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) instead and it works fine.

Comment: They are the same thing, installed as "npm install react-datepicker --save"

Comment: I use `react-bootstrap-daterangepicker` if you are looking for good alternatives.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Even I tried react-bootstrap-daterangepicker..Any solution?